# OpenVPN client: ERROR: Linux route add command failed

Tags: networking, openvpn

I am having this error using OpenVPN client:

```
Mon Sep 25 07:46:43 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Mon Sep 25 07:46:43 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.10 peer 10.8.0.9
Mon Sep 25 07:46:43 2017 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.9
ip: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mon Sep 25 07:46:43 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Mon Sep 25 07:46:43 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.9
Mon Sep 25 07:46:43 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.9
Mon Sep 25 07:46:43 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

My client configuration is :

```
dev tun
tls-client
remote myRemoteServer_IP <myRemoteServer_Port>

pull

proto udp

script-security 2

comp-lzo
reneg-sec 0

cipher AES-256-CBC

auth SHA1
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/auth.txt

log /etc/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 3


<ca>
# the certificate...
</ca>
```

I am not the server administrator so I can't change the server configuration..
I tried the same configuration on my ubuntu and it is working...

My operating system is a costumized distribution of linux, the architceture is ARM (armv5tejl), the kernel is 3.10

Any idea how to fix this? thanks!

[EDIT]

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0 
10.8.0.9 dev tun0  src 10.8.0.10 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.80
```

Comment: What does `ip route` show. You probably already have a route that conflicts with the route to `192.168.0.1/24` and the kernel refuses to add the route.

Comment: I added the ip route result, I don't know much in networking, is there a routes conflit? how can I resolve this? thanks

Comment: The last line `192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.80` shows that you already have a route to `192.168.1.0/24`, which is apparently your local LAN. Why are you trying to add the new route to `192.168.1.0/24`?

Comment: actually it is the openvpn server that is pushing the routes.

Comment: Ok. I guess the network addresses are clashing: both the server and you local network use `192.168.1.0/24`. If this is the case, you will have to either renumber you own local LAN address space, or negotiate with the openvpn server admins to use a different subnet on the remote network.

Answer (score 7):

Try once:

sudo ip link delete YOUR_NETWORK_INTERFACE

Example:

```
sudo ip link delete tun0
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is supposed to help?

Comment: It will delete the routes added by openvpn.
so next time when you try connecting by openvpn it will not throw any error by saying routes already added.

Comment: Actually, this was exactly the problem I had today, an old job OpenVPN configuration added a route that remained in place, and in my new job OpenVPN config was not working because of that. `ip link delete` command and reloading VPN solved the issue.

Comment: works!
in my case tun0 left for some reason after the previous connection, so the deletion did the job

Comment: In my case it doesnt work. (linux mint sonya running on a macbook)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a somewhat trivial answer, but in my case I solved it by rebooting the machine to resolve the conflict (to free that IP and make it available)

Comment: Evergreen solution 